# How to place a vehicle on a sculpted landscape?

Tags: animation, objects

As the heading already says, i want to place a vehicle on a landscape which was made using the Sculpt-Mode. My current vehicle has 4 wheels, but as a next step i also need to place a vehicle with 6 or 8 wheels on the ground.

I googled a while and the only solution i found was to use an active rigid body for the vehicle and a passiv rigid body for the ground from the physics tab. The problem with that is that the vehicle is jumping around like a ball (even if i use the sliders to adjust friction and bouncine). I'm looking for a solution which helps me to position the vehicle with all wheels as good as possible on top of the ground.

My first vehicle only needs to be placed on the ground, but the other vehicle(s) with 6 or 8 wheels should be animated to drive on top of the ground. For the driving part i found a tutorial on youtube which explains it on top of a plane [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rd8F57jZChk), but the positioning part is still open.

The result should be rendered as a part of a movie (it's not intended to use a game engine).

I hope i could explain my problem as good as possible and hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance
nioerd

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_bgexISCSA

Comment: Bounciness and friction aren't the problem.Check if Collision Bounds is turned on for the ground plane, and if it is, change the Bounds type to Triangle Mesh. If that doesn't work, try Convex Hull. On the other hand, if Collision Bounds is off, then turn it on.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood
I played around with the different settings of Mesh, Convex Hull with no change. The only thing which stopped bouncing was using a box but this does not solved the alignment.
Where do i find the Collision Bounds? My physics Tab looks like this [link](http://imgur.com/QxlEPQE).

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos
I watched the whole tutorial today. I think i already watched it some time ago but not with an intention to use it. Unfortunately I'am limited by a deadline and there are a lot of steps to do. You also need to install this external script ...
So I will adopt some parts of the tutorial and see how far I will get with it.

Comment: @nioerd... If you can upload your blend file I'll look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In my driving games, I use a python script that's supplied with the Blender docs for controlling my vehicles. The link to that script (and example) is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3226675/blender/vehicle_controller_demo.zip). This script makes everything a lot easier and offers greater control of your vehicle than with logic bricks.

In studying the script, you'll see that the body of the vehicle is a rigid body with Collision Bounds turned on, and it's suspended on the wheels by constraints. The wheels are set to No Collision with Collision Bounds turned on. This keeps the vehicle body off the ground plane while still letting the wheels rest on it without that jumpiness, which is normally caused by the collision between rigid bodies and static objects.